# Include an image URL from a RSS feed

Tags: images, rss

I am trying to insert a image from a blog post in to an email from a RSS feed. I can get it to inject the image, but the way it comes in it has HTML tags on it already, preventing me from adding my own style to make it fit better in the email. Please help.

[Rss Feed is Here](https://nvidianews.nvidia.com/releases.xml)

[Code sample is here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tUA1UWe_akd0IX2pKKb963C3lnMLYKd-aMlg7SWWzzY/edit?usp=sharing)